# Loading data in matching mysql-table without having the table name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a csv-file which is loaded into a db by the "LOAD DATA INFILE" function (php/mysql). In fact, I have very many csv-files. For each file there is a table in the db (though sometimes two files go into one table). Problem is: Filenames don't match tablenames. The application doesn't know which file goes into which table.

But I have the sql-statements (LOAD DATA INFILE) for each file. Is there a way to tell mysql "I have this file here, put it where the structure of the statement matches the structure of the table."?

Comment: You should keep a mapping between data files and corresponding tables. The guessing could mix things.

Comment: CSV files don't contain enough information (e.g. data types) to build a table from scratch, let alone attempt something like this.  The best you could do is roll something of your own from inspecting `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, but it sounds like you ought to take a step back and find a better design.

Comment: @Gregor I know. If I had coded the thing, I would have kept a mapping. But I only get paid to maintain the application.

Comment: You need to solve your problem using SQL only?

Comment: @eggyal I know plenty better designs. But the database design is given, I'm not allowed to change anything. Data types are contained in the mysql-statements, though. I have those.

Comment: @shnoop: You have the data types of the MySQL tables, but not of the data in the CSV files.

Comment: @eggyal I have fully functional mysql-statements, which convert the csv-data into the needed data types. That's not the problem. The statement just needs the table name.

Comment: @shnoop: I think you misunderstand my point that, unless you know the relevant table in advance (which you do not), you have no information about the CSV column data types.

Comment: @eggyal but I know the csv column data types. the mysql statement already prepares the csv-data for the matching table. it's just that the name of the table is not known by the statement. I think I'll just have to do a mapping through an array or JSON.

Comment: @shnoop: Are you suggesting that every table has the same structure?

Comment: @eggyal no - that's why there's one statement for each csv-file

Comment: @shnoop: Quite. So, if you don't know to which table each file belongs, and each table has a different structure, then you cannot know in advance what are the data types of each column in the CSV.  QED.